# I am trying to make a semi-efficient hash table in java and am ending up in an infinite loop

Tags: java, hash, infinite-loop

I have been staring at this thing for quiet some time now and I just don't see my mistake... I would be extremely grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

public class learningHash {

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
{
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(args[0]); //Read the data from the file
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    int max = 13; // array size
    int j = 0;                          // index for hash keys
    String[] mainData = new String[max];     // items array
    String[] inputData = new String[max];   // temp array
    int in = 0;                              // needed variables

    long temp;
    int loc;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {  // read file until none left

            inputData[in] = String.valueOf(input.hasNextLine());

            String[] breaks =  inputData[in].split(" "); // checks for space and splits

            if(breaks.length == 2) // if equal 2 store i.e "eco 32" will become "eco" and "32" therefore ==2
            {
               temp = hashing(breaks[0], max); // creating a hash key
                loc = (int)temp; // converting from long to int

                if(mainData[loc] != null)
                {
                    while(mainData[loc] != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Collision at [" + loc + "] with Data Item : [" + mainData[loc] + "] ");
                        loc++;
                        if(loc > max)
                        {
                            loc = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                mainData[loc] = (breaks[0]+" "+breaks[1]); // recombines i.e "moss space 25" and stores it in data location
                System.out.println("Data Item[" + mainData[loc] + "] Stored in index [" + loc + "] of array.");
            }
            else // i.e "eco' without "32" belongs into this criteria
            {
                temp = hashing(breaks[0], max); // creating a hash key
                loc = (int)temp; // converting from long to int               
                while((mainData[loc] != breaks[0]) && (mainData[loc] != null) )
                {
                    loc++;
                    if(loc > max)
                        loc = 0;
                }
                if(mainData[loc] == null)
                {System.out.println("ERROR Data item ["+ breaks[0] + "] was NOT found. ");}
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(" Data item [" + breaks[0]+ "] was found at location ["+ loc+"] .");
                }
            }
     }
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: what is the value returning by method hashing(String, int);?

Comment: It is returning a hashed type long. Which I then cast to int. I didn't post the method because I tested it separately and it worked fairly well.

Comment: if(loc > max)
                        {
                            loc = 0;
                        } check this line. remove the condition and check. i think it should outside of while loop.

Comment: I'll give it a shot!

Comment: I moved it and it wasn't what is causing the infinite loop, or rather something else is causing another if that was it. I do think that having it outside the "while and if" would cause the array to go out of bounds. Since while it is doing a simple linear probe it is increasing index loc so if at some point it goes over max it will be out of bounds.

Comment: check out my answer ;)

Comment: that was it! =)!!! I have over looked that so many times !!!! thank you!!

Comment: no problems 4 eyes see better than two :)

Comment: Absolutely, and again thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
inputData[in] = String.valueOf(input.hasNextLine());
```

should be replaced with

```
inputData[in] = String.valueOf(input.nextLine());
```

then you will read out data and not only ask if the next line is available and read the boolean out...also I think this makes an infinite loop ;)